# Windows phone store app source code lost : how to get the appx package from the dev center?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I uploaded a windows phone application on the windows store several months ago. Unfortunately, I've lost my source code (because of an hdd problem)!

Did you guys find any way to download your appx package to try to decompile it ? (From the dev center or the windows store ?)

I could't find any features of this kind on the dev center. It's too bad because it would be very usefull to me in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to download it on the dev center at this time. But I contacted the Microsoft support and they sent me the .appx file a day later. Very efficient support !

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of anyway to get it and decompile the package.   Source control is your friend here.  You can use [microsoft's free visual studio team services](https://www.visualstudio.com/?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP9102) for tfs in the cloud.  You can use tfvc or git for source control.  If you have your code in source control you will still have a copy of the code if disaster strikes

Comment: Of course, since I had this problem with my hard drive, I use git with all my new projects. I agree to say that it is very useful ! :)